# Hyperlink with spaces

Tags: vba, hyperlink, spaces

I have a worksheets for my projects.
the first sheet is the main one the containing all the name of the projects.
the author sheets are for every project.

in the main sheet the name of the project has hyperlink to his sheet.

when running the code I got a pop msgbox that I write the new project name (look for "project_name").
the code does stuff.
but near the end there is the hyperlink code. (look for ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add....)

so my problem is:
when I choose a project name like "abcd" everything works ok. But when I choose name like "ab cd". the code runs but the hyperlink doesn't work.

I realized that having a space in the project name makes the code not work.

thanks for the help.

p.s.
The notes are in Hebrew.

```
Sub New_project()


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------תחילת ריצת קוד
    Dim Start, Finish, TotalTime As Date

    Start = Timer


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ביטול חישובים ועדכוני מסך והתראות
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------החזרת חישובים ועדכוני מסך והתראות
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------פתיחת חלונית והקלדת שם הפרויקט
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------אם לחצו cancel אז יציאה מהקוד
    Dim project_name As String
    project_name = InputBox("נא להקליד את שם הפרויקט החדש")

    If Len(project_name) < 1 Then

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

        MsgBox ("יציאה מהקוד")

        Exit Sub

    End If


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------בדיקה האם שם הגיליון לפרויקט החדש כבר קיים
    Dim curSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ArraySheets() As String
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim sheet_existing As Integer

    x = 0
    sheet_existing = 0
    For Each curSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If curSheet.Name Like project_name Then

            Worksheets(project_name).Activate
            sheet_existing = 1

            Finish = Timer
            TotalTime = Format((Finish - Start) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

            MsgBox ("שם הפרויקט כבר קיים" & vbNewLine & "זמן ריצת קוד: " & TotalTime)

            Exit Sub

        End If

    Next curSheet
    'iComp = StrComp(str1, str2, vbBinaryCompare)

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------הוספת גיליון חדש בסוף הקובץ
    If sheet_existing = 0 Then

        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = project_name

    End If


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------הוספת כותרות
    Range("A1") = "#"
    Range("B1") = "תאריך"
    Range("C1") = "שלב"
    Range("D1") = "איש קשר"
    Range("E1") = "הערות"
    Range("F1") = "מסמכים"
    Range("G1") = "ימים"
    Range("H1") = "צבירה"


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------רוחב עמודה
    Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 9
    Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 11
    Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 30
    Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 16
    Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 17
    Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 9
    Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 6
    Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 10


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------הוספת מסגרת לתאים
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Set rng1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(27, 8))
        With rng1.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = vbBlack
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With


    Range("A:H").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("A:H").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter


    Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    Columns(1).Font.Bold = True


    Range("A1:H1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)


    Range("A2") = 1
    Range("B2") = Date
    'Range("C2") = "רשום כאן את השלב הראשון"
    Range("G2") = 0
    Range("H2") = 0


    Range("N1:Q1").Merge
    Range("N2:Q12").Merge

    Range("N1:Q1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)

    Range("N1:Q1") = "הערות"


 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------הוספת מסגרת לתאים
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Set rng2 = Range(Cells(1, 14), Cells(12, 17))
        With rng2.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = vbBlack
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With


    Range("N:Q").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("N:Q").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ספירת גיליונות בקובץ
    Dim SheetCountA As Integer
    SheetCountA = Application.Sheets.Count

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------העתקת כפתור חזרה לגיליון החדש
    Sheets(SheetCountA - 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(SheetCountA).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(SheetCountA).Range("K1")


    Sheets(SheetCountA - 1).Select
    Range("B1").Copy
    Sheets(SheetCountA).Select
    Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A1").Select

    Sheets(SheetCountA - 1).Select
    Range("A1").Select

    Sheets("סיכום").Select


    Dim LastRowA As Integer
    LastRowA = Application.CountA(Range("B:B"))


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------הוספת מספור לפרויקט החדש
    Cells(LastRowA + 1, 1) = Cells(LastRowA, 1) + 1


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------הוספת היפר-לינק
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(LastRowA + 1, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        project_name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=project_name

    Cells(LastRowA + 1, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(LastRowA + 1, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    Range("A1").Select


 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------זמן סיום ריצת קוד וחישוב
    Finish = Timer
    TotalTime = Format((Finish - Start) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

    MsgBox ("הדו''ח מוכן" & vbNewLine & "זמן ריצת קוד: " & TotalTime)


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------שאלה האם לעבור לקוד שמרענן את הקובץ
    Dim answer2 As Integer

    answer2 = MsgBox("?האם לרענן את הקובץ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "מעבר לקוד הבא")

    If answer2 = vbYes Then

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

        Call Refresh_file

    End If

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------שמירת הקובץ
    ThisWorkbook.Save


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------החזרת חישובים ועדכוני מסך והתראות
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the hyperlink valid, you just need to wrap the sheet name in quotes, so:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(LastRowA + 1, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    project_name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=project_name
```

becomes

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(LastRowA + 1, 2), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & _
    project_name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=project_name
```